# Code only runs properly if debugging step-by-step

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I'm making a webserver and I've come up with some very strange problems.

1. My server was running as expected
   yesterday when I turned off my laptop, but today it only sends the http
   headers (I didn't change anything)
2. When a user requests a file, if I send them using the following code, it works perfectly:

`while ((n = fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), file)) > 0)
send(ts, data, n, 0);`

but if I change it to this, it only sends ~2% of the file. And that's not a random number, it actually only sends about 2% of the file.

```
while ((n = fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), file)) > 0)
web.Send(data);

int WEB::Send(string data)
{
    return send(TempSocket, data.c_str(), data.size(), 0);
}
```

changing string to char* doesn't solve the problem.

- I'm using visual studio2010. If I run
  my code step-by-step, I am able to
  solve problem #1, everything gets sent. And that is my main
  problem. I do not understand why it
  happens. Hopefully someone can
  explain it to me.

Thanks in advance.

> > > > > EDIT:

```
int APIENTRY WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmd,int nShow)
{
    SOCKET MainSocket=0;
    MSG msg;


    RedirectIOToConsole();





    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, ListenThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);



    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }


    WSACleanup();
    closesocket(MainSocket);
    MainSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    return msg.wParam;
}

DWORD WINAPI ListenThread(LPVOID lparam)
{
    SOCKET MainSocket;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET tmpsock;
    struct sockaddr_in local, from;
    int fromlen=sizeof(from);

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);


    local.sin_family=AF_INET;
    local.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    local.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    MainSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

    if(MainSocket==INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(bind(MainSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&local,sizeof(local))!=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(listen(MainSocket,10)!=0)
    {
        return 0;
    }


    while(1)
    {
        tmpsock = accept(MainSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&from,&fromlen);
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, SlaveThread, (LPVOID)tmpsock, NULL, NULL);
    }

}

DWORD WINAPI SlaveThread(LPVOID lparam)
{
    SOCKET ts = (SOCKET)lparam;//temporary socket
......

char data[4096];
                    int n;
                    unsigned long int length = statbuf.st_size;

                    web.SendHeaders(200, "OK", format("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"%s\"", FileName.c_str()).c_str(), web.GetMimeType(ReqPath.c_str()), length, statbuf.st_mtime);
                    unsigned long int i=0,d=0;
                    while ((n = fread(data, 1, sizeof(data), file)) > 0)
                    {
                        d+=send(ts, data, n, 0);
                        i+=n;
                    }
                    printf("%i=%i=%i\n", length,i,d);
                    fclose(file);
```

Comment: is there any reason that you changed it from the working version to the non-working version?

Comment: The original version was web.send(). I still want to use that, as it makes the code neater.

Comment: I've found out what the problem was. At the end of the thread I call  web.disconnect(). That disconnect function uses cancelio, which terminates all input\output from the socket. Still, that function should only be called at the END of the thread. I don't know why it gets called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `data` is `char[]` of some size, and that `string` is `std::string` your code doesn't do what you think it does. When you pass data to `WEB::Send` it's creating a `std::string` from all the bytes in `data` up to the first 0, which probably is about 2% of the total data. You want to call `web.Send(std::string(data, n));` instead.

Also in `WEB::Send` you need to call `data.data()` instead of `c_str()` to avoid the same problems with nulls.

Answer (score 3):

C++ code which behaves differently when debugging is almost *always* an uninitialized (or incorrectly initialized) variable.

Can you show us the declaration of `data`? `TempSocket`?

You'll have to show us more code to tell you more.

Answer (score 2):

Read bytes can be not equal to actual size of your string, as you don't init `data` in loop every time. But in the first case you specify size of data equal `n` and in the second case you send of size `data.size()`. There might be trash in the end.

Answer (score 2):

As it could be seen from your source code, you're using threads. I suppose that you have to synchronize them in a proper way. Why? As you said, your program works correct if it is executed step by step in debug mode; otherwise it doesn't. The only difference between these kinds of execution (step by step or the whole program at once) are timings. Step by step is slower, and there is obviously enough time for some of your threads to finish some job. On some machines your program might work correct even if you don't change anything. It's randomness. So - you have to pay attention how do you synchronize threads.

I hope this helps.